# Get highest values from objects created with map

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, flexbox

I have dynamically added divs with nested divs to the dom. These have data-attributes:
`data-name-nr`, `data-model`, `data-price`.

What I want is to take the highest value of "data-price" to an array from each of all "data-div". In my example there is two nested divs inside the last

*More explanation*: In my example I have three div with class "frame" = I need an array with three values. In reality there night be whatever between 1 and 10 or even more.

So the outcome of my example would be

```
let array = [100,150,200]
or
let object = {1:100,2:150,3:200} //from the name-nr
```

So far I only managed to map the `data-item`s
I tried with `map.get` and other, they all gave me errors and I don't know which direction I should go. Please can you help?

Example:

HTML

```
    <div class="flex">
<div class="frame" data-name-nr="1">
  <div class="border" data-name-nr="1" data-price="100" data-div="1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="frame" data-name-nr="2">
  <div class="border" data-name-nr="2" data-price="150" data-div="1/1"></div>
</div>
<div class="frame" data-name-nr="3">
  <div class="border fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="100" data-div="1/2"></div>
  <div class="border fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="200" data-div="2/2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function functionName() {
   jQuery( ".frame .box" ).map(function() {

  const key = ['name','model','price']
  let values = [[jQuery(this).data("name-nr"),( jQuery(this).data('div')),( jQuery(this).data('price'))]]
  let result = values.map(row =>
    row.reduce((acc, cur, i) =>
      (acc[key[i]] = cur, acc), {}))
  console.log(result[0])
})
}

$(document).on('click', '.click', functionName)
```

Console

```
Object { name: 1, model: "1/1", price: 100 }  
Object { name: 2, model: "1/1", price: 150 } 
Object { name: 3, model: "1/2", price: 100 } 
Object { name: 3, model: "2/2", price: 200 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mik_a/a6jt7kb0/

Comment: So your goal would be to extract the last line from the console output you showed ?

Comment: Objective is ambiguous. You say take highest but then show results of all values. Not exactly clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok I will reframe my question. I only managed to map the content so far. Now I need to filter it.

Comment: Ulysee BN. Not only last. from the last (name:3) I need the bigger one, which happens to be last this time)

Comment: So if I can reformulate: You map to have no duplicates of `data-name-nr` and you want to filter out by lower value  (e.g: remove the lower value of items with the same name)

Comment: yes. sounds correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *hash table* by `reducing` to a hash with unique `name`s with the largest price and then take them out to the array as required.

See demo below:

```js
function functionName() {
  let hash = jQuery(".frame .box").map(function() {
    return {
      name: jQuery(this).data("name-nr"),
      model: jQuery(this).data('div'),
      price: jQuery(this).data('price')
    };
  }).get().reduce(function(p,c){
      if((p[c.name] && p[c.name].price < c.price) || !p[c.name])
        p[c.name] = c
      return p;
  },Object.create(null));
  let result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e) {
     return hash[e];
  });
  console.log(result);
}

$(document).on('click', '.click', functionName)
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.frame {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  border-top: 1px solid green;
}

.fifty {
  height: 50%;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="1">
    <div class="box" data-name-nr="1" data-price="100" data-div="1/1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="2">
    <div class="box" data-name-nr="2" data-price="150" data-div="1/1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="3">
    <div class="box fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="100" data-div="1/2"></div>
    <div class="box fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="200" data-div="2/2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="click" value="CLICK">
click
</button>
```

and the ES6 version:

```js
function functionName() {
  let hash = jQuery(".frame .box").map(function() {
    return {
      name: jQuery(this).data("name-nr"),
      model: jQuery(this).data('div'),
      price: jQuery(this).data('price')
    };
  }).get().reduce((p, c) => {
    if ((p[c.name] && p[c.name].price < c.price) || !p[c.name])
      p[c.name] = c;
    return p;
  }, Object.create(null));
  let result = Object.keys(hash).map(e => hash[e]);
  let sum = Object.keys(hash).map(e => hash[e].price).reduce((p,c) => p + c, 0);
  console.log(result, sum);
}

$(document).on('click', '.click', functionName)
```

```css
.flex{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;width:400px;height:300px}.frame{outline:1px solid red;flex:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%}.box{border-top:1px solid green}.fifty{height:50%}button{width:100px;height:35px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="1">
    <div class="box" data-name-nr="1" data-price="100" data-div="1/1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="2">
    <div class="box" data-name-nr="2" data-price="150" data-div="1/1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame" data-name-nr="3">
    <div class="box fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="100" data-div="1/2"></div>
    <div class="box fifty" data-name-nr="3" data-price="200" data-div="2/2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="click" value="CLICK">
click
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look in to this too. It is a little bit hard to read for me though with the p and c :)

Comment: `if((p[c.name] && p[c.name].price < c.price) || !p[c.name])` - if `hash` exists overwrite with the object that has the highest `price`, else add it to the `hash`... hope that is clear :)

Comment: Yes it is (somewhat) clear. I forgot in my question, that I need to make an addition with all these. So in your example i could do that on the fly I guess. I mean in the same function. (100+150+200)

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I found a problem. If I update the data-price after a click this doesn't work anymore.. if I update the whole div it does however. Can't really see why this is so. Or is it?

Comment: @Mik_A can you show me a fiddle that demos it - did not get the.problem..

Comment: I'll try. It might be in my live example and there it's too much for a fiddle.

Comment: sorry I haven't yet got any fiddles. but `code let hash = jQuery(".frame .box").map(function() { ` does not read from the dom?

Comment: eeh. how come I get old value. where is it stored? If I update the data-price by clicking a element. for eg on click -> `code $(".box").data("price", 300)`
I do get previous value all the time..

Comment: addition. When I inspect the element with chrome dev I do see I have the new value there but my function `FunctionName` retuerns the previous

Comment: I'm not so sure about that - check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4e3xjkk/

Comment: note that `$(".box").data("price", 300)` changes the `price` of all the `box`es...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q8wjacxn/
I also made a working fiddle. the problem is in my live code somewhere :(

Comment: some of your `box`es have 1px height, add `flex: 1` to `.box` and try? https://jsfiddle.net/nz644vg7/

Comment: sure, but does not effect the problem?

Comment: well, I'll take a look a little later and get back to you?

Comment: I appreciate. My fiddle however works. It is my live example that is the problem. i cannot fiddle it completely.

Comment: I found my problem. I had used `code attr('data-price', varibale)`
When I changed to `data('price', variable)` and did some `parseInt` I got the thing going. Big thanks kukkuz!!

Comment: now I have problems with parseInt :))) but should be able to sort out, I hope

Comment: accept would suffice, it would be *closed* in the sense that it will not show up in *unanswered* list... thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could select the frame and then reduce on the inside boxes:

```
$('.frame').map(function() {
    const biggerBox = $(this).find('.box').toArray().reduce((bigger, current) => 
        $(bigger).data('price') > $(current).data('price') ? bigger : current)
    const data = $(biggerBox).data()
    console.log({ name: data.nameNr, price: data.price, div: data.div })
})
```

using a fork from your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmq5jdh5/

Comment: Thanks, look like this could work. I try a real life test. I let you know!